# WPF d3d9.dll crash

Tags: wpf, crash, directx

I have several applications in WPF that periodically crash on 2 different servers (a dell poweredge and a HP proliant). The problem is that the WPF applications both crash within d3d9.dll. Rebooting the servers always fixes the problem. The problem only occurs a few times a month. Both servers are running Windows XP instead of Windows 2003.

Here is the event viewer application log entry for the crash

```
Faulting application iqlayer.exe, version 5.3.1.14, stamp 4a9d0d63, faulting module d3d9.dll, version 5.3.2600.2180, stamp 41109693, debug? 0, fault address 0x0003a756.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Once this problem occurs, all further WPF applications will not run until I reboot. I even tried running a test application which showed a blank window. The test app crashed immediately on start at d3d9.dll.

I found this [KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/967581) which i think is related to my problem. However, i didnt install directX SDK on my server and dont know where to uncheck "Break on D3D9 Error".

Comment: Try running the process in a debugger and getting a stack.  Don't forget public symbols.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b8ttk8zy.aspx

Comment: Ah, here is the stumper, I made an new project with a blank window. Crash occurs in InitializeComponent(). The stack frames not visible for any frames above InitializeComponent().

I repeated my test with 5 different WPF applications, all crashed when the first window was opened at InitializeComponent(). 

I am going to write a simple d3d device enumerator to see whats going on. Its strange that WPF apps can crash within d3d9.dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon there is no answer. I have rebooted the server and cant reproduce the problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you upgrade your video card drivers to the latest version?

Comment: not yet. I am afraid to reboot the server because from previous history, every time i rebooted, the problem went away. 

The drivers was up to date 3 months ago. I will update the drivers after i run out of things to test. The video card is a ATI FireGL. (I dont know the model yet, i will pull apart the server later today and investigate).